# I couldn't make virtual environment in visual-studio. please check this error

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, scripting, virtual

below is the screenshot of the error i got while making virtual environment in visual studio code.
there is an error message in terminal section while the myvenv (virtual environment folder) was created. actually there is not 'activate' file in Scripts folder of myvenv folder.

I cannot understand the error message, how can I handle this problem?

[image]

Comment: That error looks like a smudge of while on a black background. How about including the actual text of the error rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to upgarde your pip version : `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
or if the version doesn't work try to use 'virtualenv' instead :`python -m pip install virtualenv`
Than create an env with : `virtualenv myenv`

Comment: I could not upgrade pip with the error 'no module at pip', thus I installed seperately pip in vscode then it worked. thank you for your advice.